# why is (jQuery) after function closing bracket

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento, prototypejs

I'm working with a Magento site.  I'm running into an issue getting Magento's prototype.js to play nice with jQuery.  I've read that all of my jQuery needs to be using jQuery.noConflict(); which I've done but am still having some issues.  I have seen that some functions closing brackets are followed by (jQuery).

I'm wondering what this is for and if I need to change it to (jQuery.noConflict())?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to change `(jQuery)` to `(jQuery.noConflict())` as long as `jQuery.noConflict()` is called before that point (and after the JQuery library is included).

As you know, when you are using jQuery in no-conflict mode, you should use `jQuery` instead of `$`.

But you can use `$` instead of `jQuery` in code placed inside an immediately invoked function expression (IIFE), like this:

```
(function($) {
    // Code here can use $, instead of jQuery.
})(jQuery);
```

An IIFE is where you define an anonymous function and immediately call it. In the code above, the `jQuery` object is passed as an argument to the anonymous function, and since the parameter is named `$`, `$` represents the `jQuery` object inside the function.

Also, the `jQuery` object is passed as the first parameter to the callback function for the document-ready event, so you can do the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Code here can use $, instead of jQuery.
});
```

Which is the same as:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code here can use $, instead of jQuery.
});
```

---

Just be aware that variables declared with `var` inside an IIFE are not global. This is often a good thing, and is another reason to use IIFEs. If you do want to declare a global variable inside an IIFE, you should refer to it as a property of the `window` object.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var a = 1; // This is a global variable.
(function($) {
    var b = 2; // This is NOT a global variable.
    window.c = 3; // This is a global variable.
})(jQuery);
<script>
```